# logstash as agent to parse and send to centralized logstash server

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am working on storing my application log output into elastic search using logstash.

Initally i thought of a architecture where application server 1 and 2 will send the logs to centralized logsatsh, where we will parse the input and send it to elastic search .

But, the centralized logstash server is being used by many applications. We dont want it to junk it with logs.

[image: Centralized Logstash Parsing]

Hence, i am looking for some utility or a program which can parse the input in application server itself and send it to centralized logstash which will further forward to elastic search.

I am not sure if Logstash works kind of an agent . An architecture that i have it in mind is as below .

[image: Each application has logstash]

Instead of shipping the logs to centralized server and parsing it. Is it possible to have logstash running in application server itself where it will parse the log and send it to centralized logstash .

Just for sample conf file .

In application Server

```
input{
file{
path => "/tmp/test.log"
start_position => "beginning"
}
}
filter{
parsing logic here with grok
}
output{
Centralized logstash IP
}
```

In Centralized logstash node

```
input{
application server IP
}

output{
elastic search IP
}
```

Is it possible to implement like this or is there any other easy way to do the same.

Comment: Distributing logstash around like that is a good way to distribute the load to a group of machines without creating logstash-specific machines.  The downside is in maintenance - releasing logstash configs to a group of machines gets to be a pain (even with ansible, etc).  I like filebeat on the remote machines with a centralized logstash(es).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use this architecture.

But the problem with having a logstash doing the parsing on the application server is that Logstash can consume a lot of resources, especially if you are using grok parsing, which would impact your apps. Sometime Logstash can eat up to 99% of CPU time due to having to parse long messages.
You'll be better off using a simple shipper on your application server (like beaver or filebeat) and installing Logstash on a dedicated server.